# In TFS 2012, is there a way to "cascade" checkins from a parent branch to child branches?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Our team is using Team Foundation Server 2012 as the code repository.

We create branches per user from a release branch and merge code to that branch to move to prod.

Is there a way to automatically cascade a check in on the release branch to its child branches?

For example; There is a release branch `REL_BRANCH` and there are 3 users who work on the code. So 3 branches are created `USERBRANCH1,2,3`.

So when user1 merges his code to `REL_BRANCH`, is there a way to merge the changeset to `USERBRANCH2&3` automatically? Or is there a way to write a plugin to implement this?

Comment: What's the reason that you want to let every user work on a private branch?

Comment: Automatic merges are a bad idea. Each user should be able to choose the time they merge the changes from "prod" to their development branch. The only thing you need to enforce is that they do this before they merge their changes back to "prod".

Comment: Frankly, the best way to use TFS is ... don't use TFS.  Use Git ... or *anything* besides Visual Source Safe or Team Foundaton Server for your code base.  Honest!  Having said that, separate branches/user is a Bad Idea.  *All* users should *share* the baseline, and/or *share* specific *logical branches*.  A "branch" should be based on some special feature or sub-release.